# Is it possible to ensure a table row border is always the same? Angular ngStyle

Tags: html, css, angular, border

I am currently using Angular for my front end and having an issue where a bottom-border is different thicknesses for no apparent reason.

[image]

As you can see above the 3rd border line is thicker than the others. (The dropdown is not causing this issue, I have removed it and tested. This also happens on lower results but I kept it to 4 lines so the image wouldn't be huge.

Code used to generate the border:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let result of results;  let i = index" [ngStyle]="{
    'border-bottom': result.NEW_LINE === 1 ? '1pt solid black' : ''
    ,'border-collapse': 'collapse'
  }">
```

DevTools results for the thick line:

```
<tr _ngcontent-wgl-c5="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" class="ng-star-inserted" style="border-bottom: 1pt solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: Have you used DevTools to see where the element is getting its styles from?

Comment: I have added the line to the main post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The parenting table needs to have `border-collapse:collapse` for the 1px border-bottom to work. Collapsing border model is what makes row borders stylable.

*The edges of the rows, columns, row groups and column groups in the collapsing borders model coincide with the hypothetical grid lines on which the borders of the cells are centered. (And thus, in this model, the rows together exactly cover the table, leaving no gaps; ditto for the columns.) In the separated borders model, the edges coincide with the border edges of cells. (And thus, in this model, there may be gaps between the rows, columns, row groups or column groups, corresponding to the 'border-spacing' property.)*

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr [ngStyle]="{'border-bottom': result.NEW_LINE === 1 ? '1px solid black' : ''}">
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjootf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html